# python doctest two stage tests

Tags: python, doctest

I'm learning python by writing an interface to an XML API.  Most of the calls require an access token obtained from the login call.  Is there a way to capture the token from the login call to be used in the other calls?  i.e. is there a way to doctest the show_account call:

```
import requests

url = "http://api.peak.org/cgi-bin/api"
headers = {"Content-type": "application/xml"}

def login(account, pw):
    """
    login api call

    >>> login("aj@peak.org", "xyzzy") #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\\n<response version="0.0.1">\\n\\n<code>0</code>\\n<message>Success</message>\\n<access_token>...</access_token>\\n</response>\\n'

    """
    login_req = '''<request version="1.0.0">
    <command>login</command>
    <account>{account}</account>
    <password>{pw}</password>
    </request>
    '''.format(account=account, pw=pw)

#    print "Sending:\n", login_req
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=login_req)
    return response.text

#
# Show Account
#

def show_account(token, target):
    """
    show_account api call

    >>> login("aj@peak.org", "xyzzy") #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\\n<response version="0.0.1">\\n\\n<code>0</code>\\n<message>Success</message>\\n<access_token>...</access_token>\\n</response>\\n'
    >>> show_account("{token}", "aj@peak.org") #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\\n<response version="0.0.1">\\n<code>0</code>\\n<first_name>A.J.</first_name>\\n<last_name>Brown</last_name>\\n<message>Success</message>\\n</response>\\n

    """

    acct_req = '''<request version="1.0.0">
<command>show_account</command>
<access_token>{token}</access_token>
<target_account>{target}</target_account>
</request>
'''.format(token=token, target=target)

#    print "Sending:\n", acct_req
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=acct_req)
    return response.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem related to doctests, rather that you need `login` to return an actual token instead of just an XML string. Use an XML parsing library.

Comment: The caller of this interface is the one that uses the parsing library, but that still wouldn't fix this class of problem: you still have to get the output of login() and use it in the show_account() call, and that's what appears to be too much for doctest to handle.  I thought I'd double check because doctest is so simple to use, but I'm looking at nose2 as it's probably the real solution.

Comment: Doctests are meant to be a combination of documentation and tests. They provide a guarantee that the sample code you provide in your documentation actually works because it's been tested. So your doctests should show actual code usage. If the caller has to do XML parsing then that's what should be in your doctests. If that sounds too verbose for a docstring, then that's a sign that your API is in fact a pain to use. I really think the `login` function should return the token directly, or make a session class which has these functions methods and stores the token internally.

Comment: It's an xml api - it should not be returning anything but xml.  For a real interface library, you're probably right about making it a class and managing the token internally, but this is a simple example to ask about doctest's capabilities.